# SelectedNode Property Of TreeView Object Hangs The Form Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, winforms, powershell, treeview

I am working on a GUI script and I ran into a problem with my TreeView object. The problem occurs when I try to display the SelectedNode property or try to use the GetNodeAt() method of a TreeView that is displayed in another thread. I am able to display the TreeView object itself though. This is a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
    $form = new-object system.windows.forms.form
    $treeview = new-object system.windows.forms.treeview
    $treeview.name = "tree view"
    $treeview.add_afterselect({write-host $this.selectednode})
    $treenode = new-object system.windows.forms.treenode
    $treenode.name = "tree node"
    $treenode.text = "tree node"
    $treenode2 = new-object system.windows.forms.treenode
    $treenode2.name = "second tree node"
    $treenode2.text = "second tree node"
    $treeview.nodes.addrange(@($treenode,$treenode2))
    $form.controls.add($treeview)
    $thread = [Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace()
    $thread.Open()
    $thread.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("form",$form)
    $thepipe = $thread.CreatePipeline({$form.Showdialog()})
    $thepipe.Input.Close()
    $thepipe.InvokeAsync()
```

The issue comes with the line `$treeview.add_afterselect({write-host $this.selectednode})` When I click a node in the treeview the form will hang and I have to kill the Powershell process. The weird thing is I can display the TreeView object with no issue. Like this: `$treeview.add_afterselect({write-host $this})`. This will return the TreeView Object with no issues. I have also tried to use this instead `$treeview.add_nodemouseclick({write-host $this.getnodeat($_.x,$_.y)})`. This will also hang the form.

The problem comes from the form being displayed in another thread because when I do the same code but keep the form in the same thread I have no issues with displaying the selected node. like this:

```
    $form = new-object system.windows.forms.form
    $treeview = new-object system.windows.forms.treeview
    $treeview.name = "tree view"
    $treeview.add_afterselect({write-host $this.selectednode})
    $treenode = new-object system.windows.forms.treenode
    $treenode.name = "tree node"
    $treenode.text = "tree node"
    $treenode2 = new-object system.windows.forms.treenode
    $treenode2.name = "second tree node"
    $treenode2.text = "second tree node"
    $treeview.nodes.addrange(@($treenode,$treenode2))
    $form.controls.add($treeview)
    $form.Showdialog()
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You're abusing `$this` for something it isn't made for. Should be `{param($s,$e) Write-Host $e.Node}`

Comment: Oh that makes sense.  so $_ instead of $this. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: No, in my example $s is the sender (the treeview itself) and $e is the TreeViewEventArgs object passed on by the event

Comment: oh but $_ is the eventargs isn't it? $_.node works the same as $e.node. because I thought $this is the sender and $_ is the event. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the [`TreeViewEventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treevieweventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) method signature, you'll find that it takes two arguments, a `sender` and a `TreeViewEventArgs` object.

You can either "intercept" these by declaring your own named parameters, like so:

```
$treeview.add_AfterSelect({
    param($s,$e)

    # $e now refers to the TreeViewEventArgs
    Write-Host $e.Node
})
```

Or you can rely on the automatic event variables `$Sender` and `$EventArgs`:

```
$treeview.add_AfterSelect({
    Write-Host $EventArgs.Node
})
```

You may want to have a look at the help files for [`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849929.aspx) and [`about_Automatic_Variables`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx)

---

Don't use `$this` inside an event action - it's meant to be used as an instance reference in script method definitions, like so:

```
PS C:\> $obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{ Number = 3 }
PS C:\> $obj |Add-Member -Type ScriptMethod -Name GetSquare -Value { return $this.Number * $this.Number }
PS C:\> $obj.GetSquare()
9
PS C:\> $obj.Number = 4
PS C:\> $obj.GetSquare()
16
```